# when I install brew dart,the terminal showed zsh: parse error near `\n'

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, terminal, homebrew

When I'm trying to install dart on my mac, it shows zsh: parse error near `\n'

when I finish executing this order, install Dart 2.12 on my terminal. I run :
brew install dart@2.12
It was running, but when I ran this command:
brew unlink dart@ && brew unlink dart@ && brew link dart@
Then the terminal displays

zsh: parse error near `&&'

And I think when I take the phrase this command :
brew unlink dart@.

I thought it would work. But still Not running.  the terminal displays :

zsh: parse error near `\n'

What should I run so that it can run in the terminal when Installing Dart In the terminal

Comment: Did you forget specifying the version after `@`? It should be `brew unlink dart@2.12` and `brew link dart@2.12`

Comment: @jraufeisen okey thank you sir